# WebView app in Android Studio

Tags: javascript, java, android

I have converted my fully responsive website in to Android app using Android studio. I have also added one signal push notification. I have two questions.

1. Notification works fine but I want the notification to be opened in a separate window when I click it. what should be the code and where should I put those?
2. I want a page loading progress bar in my webview app (android studio).what should be the code and where should I put those?

My codes are as follows.

At mainactivity.java page

```
package com.example.rijvan.awebaddress;

import...

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public WebView mywebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    OneSignal.startInit(this)

    .inFocusDisplaying(OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification)
            .unsubscribeWhenNotificationsAreDisabled(true)
            .init();


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mywebView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
    WebSettings webSettings=mywebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mywebView.loadUrl("https://my web site/");
    mywebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if (mywebView.canGoBack()){
      mywebView.goBack();
    }else{
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
  }
}
```

At activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout   
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

At AndroidManifest.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.example.rijvan.awebaddress">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
 </application>
</manifest>
```

I am really new in Android. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it will help you to load webview.

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        final ProgressDialog pd = ProgressDialog.show(TestView.this, "", "Loading...", true);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webView.loadUrl("http://www.diamondflorist.com/");
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon)
            {
                pd.show();
            }
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                pd.dismiss();
            }
        });
```

and for notification you need to create a new Activity or dialog whatever you want and open this by clicking notification like this.

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class);

    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            notificationIntent, 0);

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

Hope this helps you;

Answer (score 0):

Find the answer below:

**1. I want a page loading progress bar in my webview app (android studio). what should be the code and where should i put those ?**
Try these code will work-

```
package com.example.rijvan.awebaddress;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView webView;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    @SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
    private Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message message) {
            switch (message.what) {
                case 1: {
                    webViewGoBack();
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    };


    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        } else {
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        }
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                // TODO: 5/28/2018 set your loader progress here
            }

        });
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
        webView.loadUrl("https://my web site/");
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        webView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()) {
                    handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }

        });
    }

    private void webViewGoBack() {
        webView.goBack();
    }

}
```

**2. Notification works fine but i want the notification to be opened in a separate window when I click it. what should be the code and where should i put those ?**

You can do it by passing url in one signal notification-
1. send page url in the notification for which you want to open on notification click.

2. pass that url in notification intent, for example:

   NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
               .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
       Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

   ```
   Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
   notifcationIntent.putString(URL, pageUrl);

   notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
           | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

   PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
           notificationIntent, 0);

   notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
   notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
   notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
   ```
3. In your MainActivity get the page url from the intent and load that url in webview.ex-

   if (null != getIntent() && null != getIntent().getExtras()) {
               Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
                   String url = bundle.getString(URL);
                   loadWebview(url);
    }

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I am an absolute beginner, so might I ask you something again,,   about the second question, you described about loading an URL. but i dont want any webpage to open up, I want that when my users click the notification, the content of that massage gets displayed in a new screen or dialog box or window instead of opening the app when I click it.

Comment: yes.. that you can do it by creating a new activity if you want a new page or you can also open popup in the same screen after clicking on notification.

Comment: pls rate it, if you got my answer otherwise i will send some piece of code if you need.

Comment: I am rating you ,, you deserve it anyway, but if you can send some codes that would be of great help

Answer (score 0):

Please try this below way

```
public class HtmlPageLoadActivity extends Activity{

    private WebView webView = null;

    private class WebViewOverrideUrl extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            proceedUrl(view, Uri.parse(url));
            return true;
        }

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            proceedUrl(view, request.getUrl());
            return true;
        }

        private void proceedUrl(WebView view, Uri uri) {
            try {
                view.loadUrl(uri.toString());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewOverrideUrl());
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("your url here");
    }

    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebChromeClient {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
            if (newProgress >= 100) {

            }
            setValue(newProgress);
            super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
        }
    }

    public void setValue(int progress) {

    }
}
```