# Fastest way to port a Web App to Mobile App

Tags: html, web, ionic-framework

Is there any way to port a complete Web App (which is already responsive and fully compatible with small screens, already has touch UI controls, etc.) to Android/iOS?

My Web App is barebone HTML/JS/CSS, so is super vanilla (I don't even use jQuery).

I thought I could just smash my web app into an empty Ionic-Cordova project and be good with it, but I was wondering is there is a faster/better way to do this?

Maybe a tool or service i don't know about that takes as input a folder and pops out an android/IOS executable?

Comment: I think that the easiest way to produce a mobile applicaction binary from web sources is to use cordova

Comment: i guessed so... thanks anyway

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can make a PWA ([Progressive Web App](https://web.dev/progressive-web-apps/https://web.dev/progressive-web-apps/)).

> Progressive Web Apps (PWAs) are modern, high quality applications built using web technology. PWAs offer similar capabilities to iOS/Android/desktop apps, they are reliable even in unstable network conditions, and are installable making it easier for users to find and use them.

Basically you have to add a `manifest` file in `.json` to your project root where you'll inform many things about your App like icon, name, main color, display mode (choose `standalone` if you want it to be like an real app) and etc...
(see it here: https://web.dev/add-manifest/) and link to your project pages:

```html
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
```

After that you have to make it installable (https://web.dev/codelab-make-installable/), to do that you will need a `service-worker` script in your project, you can get one here (https://glitch.com/edit/#!/make-it-installable?path=service-worker.js%3A1%3A0)

```js
const CACHE_NAME = 'offline';
const OFFLINE_URL = 'offline.html';

self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  console.log('[ServiceWorker] Install');
  
  event.waitUntil((async () => {
    const cache = await caches.open(CACHE_NAME);
    // Setting {cache: 'reload'} in the new request will ensure that the response
    // isn't fulfilled from the HTTP cache; i.e., it will be from the network.
    await cache.add(new Request(OFFLINE_URL, {cache: 'reload'}));
  })());
  
  self.skipWaiting();
});

self.addEventListener('activate', (event) => {
  console.log('[ServiceWorker] Activate');
  event.waitUntil((async () => {
    // Enable navigation preload if it's supported.
    // See https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/02/navigation-preload
    if ('navigationPreload' in self.registration) {
      await self.registration.navigationPreload.enable();
    }
  })());

  // Tell the active service worker to take control of the page immediately.
  self.clients.claim();
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  // console.log('[Service Worker] Fetch', event.request.url);
  if (event.request.mode === 'navigate') {
    event.respondWith((async () => {
      try {
        const preloadResponse = await event.preloadResponse;
        if (preloadResponse) {
          return preloadResponse;
        }

        const networkResponse = await fetch(event.request);
        return networkResponse;
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('[Service Worker] Fetch failed; returning offline page instead.', error);

        const cache = await caches.open(CACHE_NAME);
        const cachedResponse = await cache.match(OFFLINE_URL);
        return cachedResponse;
      }
    })());
  }
});
```

Just add and save it in `.js` file in your project.

After that make sure you register the service worker using that code in your project:

```js
/* Only register a service worker if it's supported */
// Service Worker
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js');
  }
});
```

Now you can make your site installable via some `<button>` element for example:

```js
window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', (event) => {
   // Get the event first
   window.deferredPrompt = event;
});

document.querySelector('#buttonInstall').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const promptEvent = window.deferredPrompt;

  if (! promptEvent) {
    return;
  }

  promptEvent.prompt();

  promptEvent.userChoice.then((result) => {
      window.deferredPrompt = null;
    });
  }
});
```

You can hide the install button when people are in your `PWA` this way:

```js
if (! window.matchMedia('(display-mode: standalone)').matches) {
  // hide your install button
}
```

Here is some important things:

- Your app have to meets certain criteria to be installable, you can
  see it here: https://web.dev/install-criteria/
- If the install pop-up doesn't appear, it means you made something
  wrong, or your manifest is broken or your script.
- You can see if your manifest.json is ok in browser developer tools open it (F12), go to `Application` tab and go to `Manifest`, this will show all your manifest parameters and it will show if something is wrong too.
- I recommend you to read all the links above, there is a lot more
  details an explanation about PWAs

Comment: While your answer is detailed and complete, it does not answer to the post. The author is asking how to create a mobile application from a website through a webview. A PWA is not a mobile application

Comment: @saperlipopette The author isn't asking about webview, is asking about the fastest way to port a web app to mobile app, the author said **maybe** a tool that pops out a executable, not specific one that does that, i think my answer is still very acceptable.

Comment: `[...] and pops out an android/IOS executable` : a PWA is not an Android/iOS executable, it a website hosted on a web server

Comment: @saperlipopette that's why i referred to `[...] maybe [...]`, the author seems not to be sure what she want, just want a fast way to do it.

Comment: I find this answer amazing, and even if is not the perfect answer (as i would have preferred to be able to post the app on apple/google store) i still think this solution is complete and worth being studied, and definitelly deserves to be recognised as valid
Thanks all for the help.

Comment: @Emanuele I found these tutorial that shows you how can you publish your PWA on Playstore or even generate a .APK when your website is all ready (meeting all criterias) https://www.davrous.com/2020/02/07/publishing-your-pwa-in-the-play-store-in-a-couple-of-minutes-using-pwa-builder/

Also, you can make a offline page for your site when people try to access it without internet connection, so instead of fallback to browser page it will fallback to your own page: https://web.dev/offline-fallback-page/

Answer (score -2):

simple way to port web app to mobile app is to make a [WebView app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50565877/webview-app-in-android-studio?noredirect=1&lq=1) in android. then give it your web app link address